# getting the first word of a string in c# using split

Tags: c#, string

i am trying to get the first word of a c# (and before you scream dupe that post  DID NOT help me) i tried split but for the life of me could not get it to work.

Comment: i now its short but its all i needed

Comment: `var s = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(' ') - 1);`

Comment: split for sure should work too `str.Split(' ')[0]`

Comment: You could also use a RegEx here, if you don't want characters that can't be part of a word. No punctuation character or numbers, etc...

    string input = "Hi! Wie geht es Dir?";
    string pattern = @"^\b[\p{L}]+\b";
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);

This would output: 

Hi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using a Split:**

```
var input = "abc def";
string[] arr = input.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
```

Output:
abc

**Optimal 1:**

```
var input = "abc def";
int startSpace = input.IndexOf(' ') - 1;
if (startSpace > 0) input = input.Substring(0, startSpace);
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Output:
abc

**Optimal 2:**

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> input = "abc dev";
int startSpace = input.IndexOf(' ');
ReadOnlySpan<char> substring = input[0..startSpace];
Console.WriteLine(substring.ToString());
```

Output:
abc